# Powershell passing element of array as argument

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I am a PowerShell novice and I am stuck :(. I wrote what was I thought a simple script to just add a list of users to an AD group. But unfortunately it doesn´t work. I have got the correct objectId in an array but then when I try to pass it as an argument it fails. Does anyway find a way forward? I feel it is something very simple but I have tried a lot of different things and well as it says I am stuck

Added some clarifications below code segment

```
$UsersToAdd = @(
    'user@domain.com',
    'user2@domain.com'
)
$ParentGroup = "DomainGroupX"

ForEach ($User in $UsersToAdd)
{
    $UserId = az ad user list --upn $User --query [].objectId
    $test = $UserId[1]
    If ($UserId.count -le 1) { echo "$User not found" }else {
        az ad group member add --group $ParentGroup --member-id $test
    }
}
```

The problem is in this line: az ad group member add --group $ParentGroup --member-id $test

this $test item is an array with one single ObjectId in it, something like this
[ "sdjasddheiieyieyie"]

But now It fails when i try to pass it whereas the below does work
az ad group member add --group $ParentGroup --member-id "sdjasddheiieyieyie"

Thank you!!

Comment: What line “doesn’t work”? What is `[].objectId` mean? If it’s supposed to be passed as a literal string value, try to quote it: `.. --query "[].objectId"`

Comment: hi sorry! This is a PowerShell applet that lets you get information from the ActiveDirectory https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/user?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-user-list

This az ad user list returns a JSON file, and with --query it looks in a JSON records and filters out the objectId parameter

Answer (score 0):

You are making your JMESPath query more complicated than it needs to be:

```
$UsersToAdd= 'user@domain.com','user2@domain.com'
$ParentGroup = "DomainGroupX"

Foreach ($User in $UsersToAdd) {
    $UserId = az ad user list --upn $User --query [0].objectId
    if ($UserId) { 
        az ad group member add --group $ParentGroup --member-id $UserId
    } else {
        "$User not found"
    }
}
```

Indexing into the JSON array from the start avoids the unnecessary complications.

---

Using `[].objectId` returns the array structure as a string around the `objectId` value. An additional problem is it formats the value you want by including a preceding space that you must consider.

```
$UsersToAdd= 'user@domain.com','user2@domain.com'
$ParentGroup = "DomainGroupX"

Foreach ($User in $UsersToAdd) {
    $UserId = az ad user list --upn $User --query [].objectId
    $UserId = $UserId[1].Trim()
    if ($UserId) { 
        az ad group member add --group $ParentGroup --member-id $UserId
    } else {
        "$User not found"
    }
}
```